# how to highlight the image on touch event in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

hi friend i created this method for image select it working proper but i am facing problem on image when i touch the image i cant see image click or  not i want highlight the image when i touch on it how can i do this

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint location= [touch locationInView:self.view];
    if(CGRectContainsPoint(firstImage.frame, location)) 
    {
        //  flag like
        select=1;        
    }
    else if(CGRectContainsPoint(secImage.frame, location))
    {
        select=2;        
    }
    [mComment resignFirstResponder];

}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event { 

    UITouch  *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject]; 
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self.view];

    if(CGRectContainsPoint(firstImage.frame, location)) {   
        if(select==1) {

            var=1;
        }}
    else if(CGRectContainsPoint(secImage.frame, location))  { 

        if(select==2) {
            vars=1;
        }}
    select=0; 
}
```

Comment: You have two images(one for normal state and the other for highlighted state)? Its better to have two images. Set the highlighted image in imageView on touchDown, and set the normal image back again on touchUp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you can do for highlight the image when you touch on it. When you touch on image you should change the alpha of selected image in touch began method and reset the image alpha in touch ended method. So its look like button.

For Ex.

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint location= [touch locationInView:self.view];
    if(CGRectContainsPoint(firstImage.frame, location)) 
    {
        //  flag like
        select=1;        
        firstImage.alpha = 0.5;
    }
    else if(CGRectContainsPoint(secImage.frame, location))
    {
        select=2;        
        secImage.alpha = 0.5;
    }
    [mComment resignFirstResponder];

}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event { 

    UITouch  *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject]; 
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self.view];

    if(CGRectContainsPoint(firstImage.frame, location)) {   
        if(select==1) {
            firstImage.alpha = 1.0;
            var=1;
        }}
    else if(CGRectContainsPoint(secImage.frame, location))  { 

        if(select==2) {
            secImage.alpha = 1.0;
            vars=1;
        }}
    select=0; 
}
```

Comment: And this UIView property ([alpha](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/alpha)) is animatable, so you can make your interface more interesting. But i'd set alpha to say 0.6 when those images are created and then make them opaque within touchesBegin handler.

Comment: @danny_23, Animatable means? what you want?

Comment: Hi. Your answer is correct. UIView has several properties that are called "animatable". I just wanted to admit that Rani could implicitly animate this property to create cool looking effect.